# This script dosn't work when I attempt to run it

Tags: javascript

When I run this script

```js
function doGet() {
  
}
var seconds = 3; // seconds for HTML
var foo; // variable for clearInterval() function

function redirect() {
    document.location.href = 'krunker.io';
}

function updateSecs() {
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
    seconds--;
    if (seconds == -1) {
        clearInterval(foo);
        redirect();
    }
}

function countdownTimer() {
    foo = setInterval(function doGet(){updateSecs()}, 1000);
}

countdownTimer();

onbeforeunload = function() {return "Stop";}; //Alert  

<p>You should be automatically redirected in <span id="seconds">3</span> seconds.
</p>
```

Absolutely Nothing happens and I don't understand why. It's supposed to stop a third-party extension (securely) from blocking this website.

Comment: Also, document.location.href = 'krunker.io' will redirect you to /local-path/krunker.io, you need to put full url with scheme (e.g. http:// or https://).

Comment: Ok, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the problem:

```
foo = (function doGet(){updateSecs()}, 1000);
```

Should it not be

```
foo = setInterval(function doGet(){updateSecs()}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yeah, I had that in there at first, but it always had an issue saying either that I am missing a colon at the product ID or there is a Syntax error.

Comment: Or it said setInterval is not defined.